# Trust Wallet SDK V2 - Signed Transaction Error

Tags: android, kotlin, blockchain, trustwallet

I've been trying to send ethereum transaction which has been signed using Trust Wallet wallet-core v2 library. Everytime I'm receiving the error "Transaction has been reverted by the EVM". Below is the code, I'm using:

```
val signerInput = Ethereum.SigningInput.newBuilder().apply {
            this.chainId = ByteString.copyFrom(BigInteger(chainValue).toByteArray()) //5A2,1442
            this.gasPrice = BigInteger("d693a400", 16).toByteString()
            this.gasLimit = BigInteger("5208", 16).toByteString()
            this.toAddress = "addressHere"
            this.transaction = Ethereum.Transaction.newBuilder().apply {
                this.transfer = Ethereum.Transaction.Transfer.newBuilder().apply {
                     this.amount = BigInteger("0348bca5a16000", 16).toByteString()
                }.build()
            }.build()
            this.privateKey = ByteString.copyFrom(walletPrivateKey.data())
            this.nonce = BigInteger("0").toByteString()
        }.build()
        val signerOutput =
            AnySigner.sign(signerInput, CoinType.ETHEREUM, Ethereum.SigningOutput.parser())
        val outputSignature = signerOutput.encoded.toByteArray().toHexString()
```

Hex String method::

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString(withPrefix: Boolean = true): String {
val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
if (withPrefix) {
    stringBuilder.append("0x")
}
for (element in this) {
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", element and 0xFF.toByte()))
}
return stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

Byte String::

```
fun BigInteger.toByteString(): ByteString {
return ByteString.copyFrom(this.toByteArray())
}

fun Long?.toHexString(): String {
return java.lang.Long.toHexString(this ?: 0L)
}
```